# Outlook 2013 rules- create a rule according to a text inside parentheses in the subject

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, email-filter, rules

I would like to create a rule which moves to another folder all the messages I recieve whom subjects starts with a certain string inside parentheses. For example:

Subject : "[bird] this is important"

In the above example I would like to move all message which has "bird" in the parentheses to a certain folder.

I have Outlook 2013

Answer (score 0):

Do you think you can afford some heuristics? I mean, if you can assume that subject in some messages will always have word `[bird]` as leftmost word in double quotes, you can ignore the rest and use condition

`with specific words in the subject`

with string

`"[bird]` (which contains only opening quote).

[image]

Is this sufficient for you?

Comment: @Idan – Try to follow the screenshot for fixed word. You did not mention extracting and using the word anywhere in your question. The question appears to be asking only about fixed bracketed word `[bird]`, maybe inside the double quotes (based on the example).

Comment: @Idan – I think I can help you. Since there are no other answers yet except mine, please re-phrase your question to clearly and exactly specify what you actually need and I will modify my answer (or I will delete it, if I won't be able to answer).